# How to create function with condition that parameter can be empty in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have function in Python Pandas like below:

```
def fk(path):
    if path:
       df = pd.read_csv(f"{path}")
    else:
         client_type = str(input())
         if client_type == "A":
            df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_A")
         elif client_type == "B":
            df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_B")
```

My idea of above function is:

- If I give path to the file (path parameter of cuntion) to my function take dataset from this path.
- If the path condition is empty choose client type and if you choose "A" take dataset from: `df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_A")` if you choose "B" take dataset from `df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_B")`

How can I repare this function because `if path:` does not work, could you modify my function based on my description above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a default argument:

```
def fk(path=None): ### EDITED THIS LINE
    if path:
       df = pd.read_csv(f"{path}")
    else:
         client_type = str(input())
         if client_type == "A":
            df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_A")
         elif client_type == "B":
            df= pd.read_csv("Data/Client_B")
```

This automatically sets `path` to `None` if no argument is passed to `fk()`.

Comment: Perfect, I gave best answer! thank you Sam Matzko :)